# Improper use of foreach in java?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to remove an item of type SubClass from an ArrayList using a foreach, and removing it right when it finds it.

The code:

```
for (SuperClass item : list)   
{     
     if (item instanceof SubClass)     
     {
        list.remove(item);     
     }   
}
```

I don't really know how the Iterator works in this case, but what I'm asking is: is this safe? Or should it throw an [out of bounds exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Even if you could do this (and some concurrent lists will allow you) it would be very inefficient i.e. `O(n^2)`.  I suggest using your IDE to transform the loop into an Iterator loop and using `Iterator.remove()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant remove items from a `list` while using ***foreach*** statement. You will get `ConcurrentModificationException`

You need to use `Iterator.remove()` method

```
for(Iterator<SuperClass> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
     SuperClass s = i.next();
     if(s instanceof SubClass) {
        i.remove();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```
List<SuperClass> sampleList = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();
ListIterator<SuperClass> listIterator = sampleList.listIterator();
//
listIterator.remove();
//
```

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) it writes that: `remove() 
          Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next or previous (optional operation).` I suspect that the comment lines represent the lines that should contain the actual foreach statements that use the Iterator?

Answer (score 0):

As sanbhat say it is not safe.
but what you want to do can be solve by 2 diffenret way.

1) you can store all the objects & after foreach loop you can remove by index.
but it is not good way.

2) use for loop (not foreach loop) & ittrate till length. then if object found remove it. thats it.

(make sure you have written condition like i